# Format Date - Moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I return from my controller a datetime with value **15/01/2016 14:15:00**
In my view, i use 
"data-bind="text: moment(MyDateTime)format('D/MM HH:mm')"
On screen show **15/01 12:15**, but on console from Chrome **2016-01-15T14:15:00Z**

I try use .utc(), but not working.

Comment: Can you provide a code block, or a js fiddle or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$("#foo").val(moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="foo" />
```